# Как работать с буфером обмена в wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, cmake, wxwidgets

Пишу ограничение для поля ввода только латиницы и кириллицы. Сделал чтобы нельзя было написать какой либо не нужный символ.

```
  txtBlock->Bind(wxEVT_CHAR, [=](wxKeyEvent& event)
      {
          // Получаем введенный символ
          const wxChar keyCode = event.GetUnicodeKey();

  // Задаем список разрешенных символов (латинские буквы и цифры)
  const wxString allowedChars = wxT("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ1234567890~`!@\"#$;%:^&?*()-_=+[]{}\\|/");

  // Проверяем, является ли вводимый символ разрешенным
  if (!allowedChars.Contains(keyCode))
  {
      // Если символ не разрешен, меняем цвет текстового поля на красный

      lblErrorPress->SetForegroundColour(wxColour(255, 0, 0));
      lblErrorPress->Show();
      lblErrorPress->Refresh();

      // Предотвращаем ввод символа
      event.Skip(false);
      return;
  }
```

Мне надо, чтобы по аналоги работал и буфер обмена. Кто может подсказать как это реализовать?